# How to make a sidebar with full height in Bootstrap 4 using flex?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Should be a very simple problem, yet too much for a noob like me :-/

Goal: The second row (sidebar + main-content) should stretch to the end of the screen, using flex in Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.5

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12 header">
            HEADER
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
            SIDEBAR
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-10 main-content">
            CONTENT
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Flex is of course enabled.

The only solution that worked somehow is to set `.sidebar { min-height:100vh; }`, but this leads to "too much height" i.e. header + viewport height, so there's a scrollbar even with empty content. All attempts with `min-height:100%` and such didn't work.

I could rearrange the setup and simply place `.header` inside `.main-content`, but I like to make my life unnecessarily difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late then never i guess.

Do you have anything above or below the div you want to be full height?

If you for example got a navbar at the top with a height of 50px you should do 100vh minus the 50 px.

**For example:**

```
min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
```

That will make the div 100% height minus the 50px from the Navbar ( which will remove any "hidden content" aka scrollbar )

Comment: Neat solution, thanks, but according to [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)[/link] `calc` is 'an experimental technology'. I solved it via creating a wrapper with `min-height:100vh` which wraps the whole body and inside it I placed the flex layout.